# Flutter showModalBottomSheet below app bar

Tags: flutter, dismiss, appbar, barrier, flutter-showmodalbottomsheet

I try to show modal bottom sheet on google map page but I need the barrier to be below the app bar for using back button. I can't acheive that.
Then I thought to replace it with bottom sheet but the map will be enabled and I don't want that.

I need the modal bottom sheet below the app bar and not dismissable ..

[image: Check attachment:]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found workaround solution with two steps: 
1- I used **BottomSheet** instead of **ModalBottomSheet**.  
2- I add **ModalBarrier** above the map to disable interactive with it.

In this case appbar still active.

That's all !